# split the string data and build a xml string by using linq to xml format in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

trying the split the string data and build into xml format using linq to xml,but i am facing some difficulities to generate a xml string

```
mystring = {1:abcd}{2:efgh}{3:/r/n:12:mmm/r/n:65:nnn}
```

required output :

```
<MESSAGE>
<BLOCK1>
<VALUE>abcd</VALUE>
</BLOCK1>
<BLOCK2>
<VALUE>efgh</VALUE>
</BLOCK2>
<BLOCK3>
<TAG>12</TAG>
<VALUE>mmm</VALUE>
<TAG>65</TAG>
<VALUE>nnn</VALUE>
</BLOCK3>
</MESSAGE>
```

Kindly advice on the above same

Comment: `i am facing some difficulities` Which difficulties?

Comment: to construct the linq to xml query,i am trying this  XDocument doc =  new XDocument(
                                             new XElement("MESSAGE",
                                             stringToPrint.Split()
                                             .Select((item, pos) => new XElement("filed" + (pos + 1), item))

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = {1:abcd}{2:efgh}{3:/r/n:12:mmm/r/n:65:nnn}
```

- First use Regex to get matching patterns of brackets.

`1:abcd` `2:efgh` `3:/r/n:12:mmm/r/n:65:nnn`

- Then with the resulting strings that contain your strings build your xml.  You may want to replace all the `/r/n` with empty space as in `"3:/r/n:12:mmm/r/n:65:nnn".Replace("/r/n", "")`.  Then to call `.Split(':')` to turn it into an array.
- From there you are going to have to develop your logic to parse the string array into your nodes.  It appears if the value can be `int.TryParse(string, out int value)` then it goes into a TAG element otherwise a VALUE element.
- And of course skip any empty array elements.  You can do that in your Split with `Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` if you are ok not seeing them in your resulting array.